# Best practices for hardware package organization?

Tags: ros, hardware, best-practices, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have recently started to invest significant time into developing ROS packages for my work and have a question regarding best practices and/or suggestions when it comes to code organization.  Specifically my question is as follows:

**When developing packages for hardware, should I aim to develop ROS-specific code or start with a general purpose library and then extend it to work with ROS via a wrapper or base class?**

I would like to have my code be reusable outside of ROS if necessary and thus avoid any ROS-specific types/functions in the library but I got a bit confused when I try to utilize any ROS functionality (e.g., rosconsole messages, service callbacks, etc.).  My current thoughts are to develop the hardware interface as a standalone class/library and then inherit it as a base class to another ROS-specific class that adds callback member functions for services and the like...  I figure this might just be a preference thing but thought I would try to get some feedback on the topic while I am still in the early stages of integration.

Thanks,
Brett

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222902/best-practices-for-hardware-package-organization?/) by [BrettHemes](https://answers.ros.org/users/20527/bretthemes/) on ROS Answers with karma: 525 on 2015-12-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I agree with your thinking.  Unless the device interface is very simple, best practice involves writing a hardware-specific library or class interface which can be wrapped in a relatively small ROS node.

The ROS-agnostic library needs to be careful how it reports errors, since it lacks direct access to the ROS logging and diagnostic services. There are various reasonable solutions: throwing C++ exceptions; using return codes; providing error status and diagnostic status interfaces; etc.

Sometimes, when data copying overhead is significant, it's worth providing access to ROS messages from within the library. For example, a camera driver may want to return its data directly in a [sensor_msgs/Image](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Image.html) structure. Depending on how it's done, that might or might not require the library to include some ROS message headers.

You are welcome to join the [ROS drivers special interest group](http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Drivers). It has been active for several years, discussing these and similar questions on a relatively low-volume mailing list.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2015-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1